# How can I run a program at a specific time repetitively on WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run two programs every 24 hours. One (program1) is supposed to start at 00:00 and the other one (program2) is to start at 23:59 . I tried using crontab as follows:

```
00 00 * * * /home/user/DESKTOP/program1
59 23 * * * /home/user/DESKTOP/program2
```

both programs are already compiled and saved in the same directory on the server. I even tried to run a basic hello world c program but it still doesn't work. Most examples I found were using bash scripts I don't if I should create a bash file instead to run the executable files.

Comment: this is a crontab issue, has nothing to do with C or your code. Unless you want the C programs to be running all the time, and they can check the system time periodically and execute whatever task you want them to run at the appropriate time.

Comment: how can I check the system time periodically before executing because I usually run compile and run in the terminal on WSL

Comment: Basically you would just sleep the vast majority of the time.  You can wake up every N seconds, or you can sleep the whole time and let the OS wake you up, which may be slightly late.  Your program would always be running and never be executing essentially.   *meaning* the OS wouldnt give your process a time slice  *the vast majority of the time* to exec anything since you would be a sleeping/low priority thread/process.

Comment: [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime), but I would get crontab working ,, time-based job scheduling is what it does. No need to try to duplicate crontab's functionality in your program (you won't do it as well anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly i would try a very simple test, more simple than the ones you have tried.

run `crontab -e` then at the bottom of the list enter `* * * * * touch ~/crontab.touched`.

This will touch a file in your home dir every minute, just go to the user dir `cd ~` and then `ls -al` to see the timestamp on this file, it should always be upto date.

This test will show you that the task is actually running.

You can also run `crontab -l` to list all the running cron tasks.

I am running WSL 1 and i did not need to change any permissions on any files/folders/user groups to make this run.

Once you have the simple case running i would then look at running your programs on a small time period for testing like every 5 minutes or so `*/5 * * * * /home/user/DESKTOP/program1`

My last question is around the path to program1, it does not look correct. In WSL go to the directory that holds the program you want to run and type `pwd` this will show you the directory you need to use in the crontab expression. Basically if you can run the program whilst in the home dir `cd ~` then it should run in cron.

let me know how you get on.